# Is there an easy way to remove all the Ubuntu Logos for a Ubuntu Custom LiveCD?

Tags: boot, live-cd, custom-distributions

I've made a Custom Ubuntu LiveCD, and it's up and running, but now I have the task of removing all the Ubuntu Logos that I am unable to use in my Custom Distribution.

Is there an easy to do this ?

Also when my distribution boots from the CD I have made, it still says Ubuntu 16.04 on the splash screen, how do I change this?

I would also like to remove the Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu screen, is that possible?

Comment: @user535733 I find that very odd then, as looking at this page [DerivativeDistroHowto](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeDistroHowto) it mentions several things on this page.

Like for example Logos in packages, and says they must be removed.

It also mentions that it is possible to use the ubuntu servers as sources of binary packages, but suggests that should the distro become large enough to then try and create your own repository or partial repository.

Comment: Ah, the policy has changed.  Good catch.

Comment: @user535733 no problem, I was hoping there would be or is an easy way to replace them, so am hoping they are stored separately to the source and as such easy to swap out and replace.  Yet I have been unable to find any mention of how to do it.

Comment: Ubuntu branding is not stored separately. It's not easy.

Comment: @user535733 Really? that then makes it very difficult to make a derivative distro as updating the packages would then mean the icons come back in again!  My changes would be lost along with the new icons I made.